# WPF: Cannot get an exception while invoking on ui thread

Tags: c#, wpf, invoke, dispatcher, ui-thread

How does the WPF Dispatcher.Invoke() behaves if it is called on the UI-Thread itself?

By reading the official .net 4.5.1 sources, I found two interesting places.

First place:

```
    public void Invoke(Action callback, DispatcherPriority priority, ...)
    {       
        (... guards...)

        // Fast-Path: if on the same thread, and invoking at Send priority,
        // and the cancellation token is not already canceled, then just
        // call the callback directly.
        if(!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested && priority == DispatcherPriority.Send && CheckAccess())
        {
            (... synchronization context switch...)
            callback();
            return;
        }

        // Slow-Path: go through the queue.
        (... ...)
    }
```

... so call on the UI-Thread with priority Send are called directly. OK!

Second place:

[link to official source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/src/Base/System/Windows/Threading/DispatcherOperation.cs#214)

DispatcherOperation.Wait(TimeSpan)

```
<-DispatcherOperation.Wait()
<--Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherOperation, CancellationToken, TimeSpan)
<---Dispatcher.Invoke(Action, DispatcherPriority, CancellationToken, TimeSpan)
<----Dispatcher.Invoke(Action, DispatcherPriority)

if(_dispatcher.Thread == Thread.CurrentThread)
{
    if(_status == DispatcherOperationStatus.Executing)
    {
        // We are the dispatching thread, and the current operation state is
        // executing, which means that the operation is in the middle of
        // executing (on this thread) and is trying to wait for the execution
        // to complete.  Unfortunately, the thread will now deadlock, so
        // we throw an exception instead.
        throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.Get(SRID.ThreadMayNotWaitOnOperationsAlreadyExecutingOnTheSameThread));
    }

    // We are the dispatching thread for this operation, so
    // we can't block.  We will push a frame instead.
    DispatcherOperationFrame frame = new DispatcherOperationFrame(this, timeout);
    Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
}
else...
```

If Invoke(...) has been called on the UI thread with another priority than Send, then it should throw an exception. So i tryed to get this exception, just for fun, but didn't succeed. Here is the code I used for that purpose:

```
    private void UIElement_OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        msLogger.Info("UIElement_OnMouseDown begin");

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
        {
            msLogger.Info("BeginInvoke");
        }));

        Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
        {
            msLogger.Info("Invoke");
        }));

        msLogger.Info("UIElement_OnMouseDown end");
    }
```

I expect an exception at Invoke-call... but no exception occurs... And the log lines are in following order:

1. UIElement_OnMouseDown begin
2. BeginInvoke
3. Invoke
4. UIElement_OnMouseDown end

... so it means that the Invoke call flushed the whole queue until the invoked-action has been processed!!! This "DoEvents"-implementation is much more simple than the implementation proposed in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherframe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). At the same time it can lead to very strange and dangerous behaviors.

Why does the previous code sample executes and doesn't throw any exception?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In official documentation that exception is not mentioned so it should not come http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591593(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Do you have any unmanaged code anywhere in the solution?

Comment: `Dispatcher.Invoke(...) method throws an exception if it is called on the UI thread with another priority than DispatcherPriority.Send` - Where have you read that? That's completely false statement. Can you cite a reference for this?

Comment: I can't find the piece of source code you mention in http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/src/Base/System/Windows/Threading/Dispatcher.cs where do you get your source from?

Comment: Hi, I added information you ask for in the question

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the answer is: the field DispatcherOperation._status doesn't currently have the value DispatcherOperationStatus.Executing. The DispatcherOperation that is currently running is not the one we want to call...